# Stronger version(2) of Isolation Lemma for linear forms

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Klivans and Spielman give isolation lemma for linear forms in their paper [Randomness Efficient Identity Testing of Multivariate Polynomials](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~klivans/ran3.ps). Lemma 4 in this paper says.

> "Let $C$ be any collection of distinct linear forms in variables $z_1\ldots z_l$ 
>   with coefficients in range {$0,\ldots, K$}. 
>   If $z_1,\ldots,z_l$ are independently chosen uniformly at random from set $S = \{0\ldots Kl/\epsilon\}$, 
>   then with probability greater than 1-$\epsilon$, 
>   there is a unique form of minimal value at $z_1,\ldots,z_l$".

Is there a stronger version of this lemma? Namely, can we choose set $S$ to be of size sublinear in $K$? Assume that $l$ is small compared to $K$.

Let me introduce a different notion of "stronger". Suresh Chari, Pankaj Rohatgi and  Aravind Srinivasan give **Generalized isolating lemma** in their paper [Randomness-Optimal Unique Element Isolation, With Applications to Perfect Matching and Related Problems](http://ecommons.cornell.edu/handle/1813/6129). Lemma 2[Generalized isolating lemma] in this paper says

> Let ($S$, $\mathcal{F}$) be any set system  and let $Z$ be a give upper bound on the size of unknown family $\mathcal{F}$. There is a simple scheme which uses $O(\log Z + \log N)$ random weights to assign integer weights to the $x_i$'s in the range $[0,N^7)$ such that with probability atleast $\frac{1}{4}$, there is a unique minimum weight set in $\mathcal{F}$. 
>   Here $S=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots x_N\}$ and $\mathcal{F}\subset2^S$.

Do we have something similar for isolating linear forms? Namely, if we know that number of linear forms is bounded by $Z$, can we reduce random bits as compared to $O(N\log(KN))$ random bits used in [Randomness Efficient Identity Testing of Multivariate Polynomials](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~klivans/ran3.ps). We also want that weights should not be too large, again weights sublinear in $K$ should be interesting.

Comment: First part of question has been solved by domotorp. But I think it's still interesting to reduce number of bits when we know that number of linear forms is bounded by some $Z$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question, if $l=1$, then $\frac{K^\frac 23}\epsilon$ is sufficient. This follows the fact that the lower envelope of some lines has the same complexity as the upper convex hull of its dual point system and if you have a convex polygon with integer vertices in $[0,K]^2$, then it can have at most $O(K^\frac 23)$ sides. I know I did not explain the details, but this is anyhow only a partial answer to your question...

Comment: Nice observation!  In fact, plugging this directly into Klivans and Spielman's proof reduces their bound from $Kl/\epsilon$ to  $O(K^{2/3}l/\epsilon)$.

Comment: Then up to the $l$ factor, this is best possible, as the above also gives a construction with $\Omega(K^\frac 23/\epsilon)$ non-unique minimal values.

Comment: @ domotorp, can you please explain your answer in more details? I  do not have a heavy mathematics ground, so cannot understand your answer. If you can provide some details and also point to relevant definitions and techniques, it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: For the definition of lower envelopes, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davenport%E2%80%93Schinzel_sequence#Application_to_lower_envelopes

Comment: For duality, see: http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/compgeom/notes/schreiber.pdf

Comment: @ domotorp, any references for the fact that "if you have a convex polygon with integer vertices in $[0,K]^2$, then it can have at most $O(K^\frac 23)$ sides"

Comment: I can give you the proof instead. Suppose it has $8K^\frac 23$ sides. Direct them clockwise. Each becomes a vector from $[-K,K]^2$ and each vector can occur at most once. In one of the quadrants, say $[0,K]^2$, there are at least $2K^\frac 23$ vectors. At most $K^\frac 23$ of these are in $[0,K^\frac 13]^2$. The rest are either long in the $x$-direction or in the $y$-direction. But having $\frac 12 K^\frac 23$ vectors of length $\ge K^\frac 13$ pushes us out from [0,K].

Comment: @domotorp, almost understood your argument. But few confusions. When you say "vector", you mean difference of end points of sides? And also, when you say "But having $\frac{1}{2}K^{\frac{2}{3}}$ vectors of length $\geq K^{\frac{1}{3}}$ pushes us out from $[0,K]$", I don't really get this statement.

Comment: 1-yes, I mean that difference.

Comment: 2-the vectors that belong to the $[0,K]^2$ quadrant must come after each other as the sides of the convex polygon. This means that if you sum all of them up, you get a vector between two vertices of the polygon. That should be again in $[0,K]^2$, but it won't be, as the sum of either the $x$- or the $y$-coordinates will be bigger than $K$.

Comment: @domotorp, For sum to be bigger than $K$, don't we need $K^{\frac{2}{3}}$ vectors instead  of $\frac{1}{2}K^{\frac{2}{3}}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, so then let us start with 16 instead of 8.

Comment: @domotorp, Many many thanks for your patience. I think I understand your solution now.